# What noticeable impacts on a human body if every ocean turns into dead sea?

Tags: apocalypse, survival, natural-disasters, water-bodies

Suppose the salinity of all the ocean in the world rivals the dead sea, using time lapse to illustrate how would an average healthy adult human being is susceptible to the aftermath of inhospitable ocean. Start with the air composition and work towards how would any one could have survived by the end of a decade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Air:**

With the salinity of the water heightened to such levels evaporation would decrease slightly. This in turn causes fewer rainfall on the areas on the land. The most prominent factor that will come into play is the severe reduction of algae (though maybe some can adapt fairly quickly since they're single celled organisms and might become adapted to the salinity within a couple of years.) This cripples for a big part the CO2 -> O2 conversion, causing an increase of CO2 in the atmosphere.
The Heightened CO2 content of the air will cause the greenhouse effect already set in motion to be amplified, increasing average temperatures on the entire planet. (With all devastating effects to the polar caps and pretty much every ecosystem that's dependent on a certain climate which will certainly shift)
Source for algae generating oxygen: http://www.ecology.com/2011/09/12/important-organism/

**Food**

Not only will the atmospheric implications be massive on a global scale, mostly because the algae that scrub CO2 from the atmosphere and generate oxygen (to an even greater extent than the rain forests do) The entire food chain in the oceans will also collapse, even if by some miracle everything in the seas and oceans at the present manages to deal with the toxicity of the high salt content. What doesn't die of the poisonous effects of salt, will die from starvation not much later. This will impact humanity the quickest as, especially fishing dependent communities will experience famine very quickly.

**Coastal lines**

The coastal lines will change as the polar ice sheets melt due to the heightened CO2 content in the air. Many beachfront cities and lowlands will flood by the sea invading. Dykes and reclamation efforts aren't likely to be viable as salinaty of the soil below will render agriculture nigh impossible (if not at all. I know that in some places in The Netherlands where I live salinity of the soil, especially in reclaimed lands is already problematic with the current levels of salt in the ocean. I can only imagine it would be a thousandfold worse when every sea and ocean on earth matched the Dead Sea's salinity.

**Humans themselves**

Humans not reliant on any of the before mentioned systems might actually not notice the immediate effects as harshly as those who are affected by floods, fishing and agriculture in reclaimed lands. But once the greenhouse effect goes haywire due to algae going extinct and a massive natural mechanism for CO2 scrubbing removed, not only Earth's temperature will rise sharply, it will also render the atmosphere toxic causing an array of health problems, especially for those with preexisting respiratory conditions. Once the other ecosystems on land start to collapse and food becomes a global shortage, people living further away from the sea will become affected by this.

In short:

-Rainfall might decrease slightly due to reduced evaporation due to the heightened salt content of the water.

-CO2 levels will rise because Algae and other aquatic plants will largely or even fully succumb to the heightened salt content of the water.

-Food chains in the ocean will collapse causing famine most prominent in communities reliant on their food/income from fishing. (Mass extinction scenario)

-A lot of people living in low lands, coastal cities and the Netherlands will be displaced due to the sea invading the land.

-Land reclamation becomes problematic due to salinity of the soil rendering agriculture impossible.

-A lot of people will starve in the long run due to a mass extinction event.

---

This part is highly speculative and not necessarily based on fact. It's what I think will happen on a longer term.

Above are  the more immediate effects of the increased Salinity of the oceans. With the oceans dead and the greenhouse effect going haywire the life on land will quickly enough follow suit with the oceanic life. As the atmosphere heats up the oceans become even more inhospitable as they inevitable warm up as well, aren't able to hold as much gasses as they do currently further aggravating the greenhouse effect.

Plants and animals on land start dying too due to the rapid shift of climate and ecosystems collapsing as food supplies dwindle for both animals and humans alike. The atmosphere becomes progressively toxic as CO2 levels are on the rise and the  usual compensation mechanisms within the ecosystem (Algae and plants) have already failed or are failing.

I think very few people will survive, but given human ingenuity, they might survive.

Comment: Good answer, but I'm pretty confident humans will survive. Humans are like cockroaches, you can't get rid of us unless you scrub the whole biosphere down to single celled organisms. There will be plenty of survivors to start over in a hotter drier world.

Comment: Yea, it's likely humans will survive, but since the atmosphere turns toxic you get cities covered by domes to form their own micro climate... Geo-engineers, do your work~!